# How can I filter a dimension in MDX Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

I use `SSAS` and `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I want select `Product` that exist inside `productcategory` that named 'Accessories'.

How I can filter a dimension ?

I write a `MDX Query` like this :

```
SELECT 
Filter(
        [Dim Product].[Hierarchy].[ProductCategory] , 
        [Dim Product].[state] =  1
       )
       On Columns
From [Adventure Works DW]
```

But I got an error :

```
Executing the query ...
Query (4, 10) The CURRENTMEMBER function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1    
argument. A member expression was used.

Execution complete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of filtering anything :

```
SELECT    
  [Dim Product].[Hierarchy].[ProductCategory].[Accessories] On Columns 
From [Adventure Works DW]
```

[edit] not sure to understand what you want to achieve - how about that - still no need of this Filter function :

```
SELECT 
  [Dim Product].[Hierarchy].[ProductCategory]  On Columns
From [Adventure Works DW]
where [Dim Product].[state].[1]
```

Comment: excuse me I change my query. i want filter a dimension when another dimension is X